# What can cause Chrome tabs to stop responding without crashing or using CPU?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Often when playing [CodeCombat multiplayer](http://codecombat.com/play/ladder/dungeon-arena), or [simulating matches](http://codecombat.com/play/ladder/dungeon-arena#simulate), especially with multiple tabs going at a time, I'll see my tabs stop responding. CPU usage goes to about 1%, but all animations on the page stop, JavaScript stops responding, and the dev tools interface sort of responds but can't actually do anything. I have to end the tab's process from the Chrome task manager.

This happens in Chrome Beta (34) through Canary (35), but not in stable (33).

I'm pretty sure it's not some sort of weird localStorage deadlock, and we're not using any synchronous networking, and it happens in incognito mode without any extensions, so what could it be?

*Update*: It has since stopped happening, so presumably Chrome fixed some bug.

Comment: can you specify the FlashPlayer version ?

Comment: 13.0.0.133, but we're not using Flash.